# Return string length smaller then input string length

Tags: c

I'm trying to set different values to char's into string from `agrv`.
For example execute cmd line:

```
./programm_name abc
```

So `argv` length is `3`, but `s` length is `1`.
I'm really don't undersatnd why :(

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

string shift(string s);

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
      printf("Usage: ./programm_name keyword\n");
      return 1;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
  {
      if(isdigit(argv[1][i]))
      {
        printf("Usage: ./programm_name keyword\n");
        return 1;
      }
      break;
  }
  string keyword = shift(argv[1]); // here argv[1] length is 3
  return 0;
}

string shift(string s)
{
    for(int i = 0, int n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] >= 65 && s[i] <= 90)
        {
            s[i] = s[i] - 65;
        }
        else if(s[i] >= 97 && s[i] <= 122)
        {
            s[i] = s[i] - 97;
        }
        printf("%i\n", s[i]);

    }
    return s; // here s length is 1
}
```

Comment: What is `string`? There's no such standard type in C.

Comment: And what is the `shift` function supposed to to? Toggle between upper- and lower-case? Then look into [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) and [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower), together with [`isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) and [`islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when doing

> ```
>    else if(s[i] >= 97 && s[i] <= 122)
>    {
>        s[i] = s[i] - 97;
>    }
> ```

with *s* being "abc" you replace 'a' by 0 (then 'b' by 1 and 'c' by 2)  so the first character becomes 0 and the length of the string becomes 0 for any function where the null character indicate the end of the string.

Why are you doing `s[i] = s[i] - 97;` or equivalent ? What is your goal ?

> return s; // here s length is 1

no, it is 0 when the input is "abc" or "ABC"

---

Do not use (ascii) code as literal integer, use 'a' etc

```
string shift(string s)
{
    for(int i = 0, int n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            s[i] = s[i] - 'A';
        }
        else if(s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')
        {
            s[i] = s[i] - 'a';
        }
        printf("%i\n", s[i]);

    }
    return s;
}
```

To know if a character is an alpha I also recommend you to use *isalpha*

Note rather than to do `for(int i = 0, int n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)` you can just do `for(int i = 0; s[i] != 0; i++)` and it is better to type *i* with `size_t` rather than *int* because this is the type for an index (it is the one returned by *strlen* etc)

---

Comment: thanks!
What if I need a 0 in the middle of string, or in the begining?

Comment: @krknc I don't know, you do not said what you want to do

Comment: @krknc _Return string length smaller then input string length_ smaller of how much ?

Comment: @krknc you *can't* have a `0` in the middle of a C string: it marks the end of the string.